# How to make html + flash graphics?

Tags: html, flash, canvas, charts, graphic

I've seen many websites using flash to render their graphics using dynamic data. 
How can I do this to put in a user account page, where it shows some dynamic data?

Comment: Your question is quite vague. I'd recommend adding more detail to further describe what you are trying to achieve and show/explain what you have already tried to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common ways of getting external data into a SWF are:

1. You can pass data to an embedded SWF using [FlashVars](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html)
2. The SWF can load [XML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html) or [JSON](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) data by loading a file from the server (using a [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html))